# Perspective Matrix not rendering proper range

Tags: opengl, matrix, lua, directx, projection

When drawing to screen, my 3D models all look fine, but the camera clipping is very wrong. I have my camera set to clip between 1mm (near) and 10m (far). Near clipping seems to happen closer to 1m and far never seems to clip at all. I have tried both the GLM implementation:

```
function mat4:perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far)
    assert(aspect ~= 0)
    assert(near ~= far)

    local t = math.tan(math.rad(fovy) / 2)
    local result = mat4(
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0
    )

    result[1]  = 1 / (t * aspect)
    result[6]  = 1 / t
    result[11] = -(far + near) / (far - near)
    result[12] = -1
    result[15] = -(2 * far * near) / (far - near)

    return result
end
```

And the DirectX implementation:

```
function mat4:perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far)
    assert(aspect ~= 0)
    assert(near ~= far)

    local result = mat4(
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0
    )

    local yScale = 1 / math.tan(math.rad(fovy) / 2)
    local xScale = yScale / aspect

    result[1]  = xScale
    result[6]  = yScale
    result[11] = far / (near - far)
    result[12] = -1
    result[15] = near * far / (near - far)

    return result
end
```

And neither seem to give the right clipping, though both look fine (no distortion).

```
self.projection = self.projection:perspective(45, 1920/1080, 0.001, 10)
```

Perhaps someone could point me to another culprit that might be causing this?

Edit: Here is a snip from the shader I am using for my scene:

```
#ifdef VERTEX
    #define v_position vertex_position
    attribute vec3 v_normal;
    attribute vec4 v_bone;
    attribute vec4 v_weight;
#endif

varying vec3 f_position;
varying vec4 f_color;
varying vec2 f_uv;
varying vec3 f_normal;

varying vec2 f_uv_reflect;

#ifdef VERTEX
    uniform mat4    u_projection;
    uniform mat4    u_model;
    uniform mat4    u_view;

    // this is why I want UBOs...
    uniform mat4    u_bone_matrices[200];
    uniform int     u_skinning = 0;

    mat4 getDeformMatrix() {
        if (u_skinning != 0) {
            return u_bone_matrices[int(v_bone.x)] * v_weight.x +
                    u_bone_matrices[int(v_bone.y)] * v_weight.y +
                    u_bone_matrices[int(v_bone.z)] * v_weight.z +
                    u_bone_matrices[int(v_bone.w)] * v_weight.w;
        } else {
            return mat4(1.0);
        }
    }

    mat3 getNormalMatrix(in mat4 deform_matrix) {
        return mat3(deform_matrix * u_model);
    }

    vec4 position(mat4 transform_projection, vec4 vertex_position) {
        mat4 deform_matrix = getDeformMatrix();
        vec4 f_position4 = u_view * u_model * deform_matrix * v_position;
        f_normal = getNormalMatrix(deform_matrix) * normalize(v_normal);
        f_color = VertexColor;
        f_uv = VertexTexCoord.xy;
        f_position = vec3(f_position4) / f_position4.w;

        // This is confirmed bork on AMD 7970 - not sure what's up.
        vec3 e = normalize(f_position);
        vec3 n = normalize(getNormalMatrix(deform_matrix * u_view) * v_normal);
        vec3 r = reflect(e, n);
        float m = 2.0 * sqrt(
            pow(r.x, 2.0) +
            pow(r.y, 2.0) +
            pow(r.z + 1.0, 2.0)
        );
        f_uv_reflect = - r.xy / m + 0.5;
        f_uv_reflect.x *= -1.0;

        return u_projection * f_position4;
    }
#endif
```

Here is the relevant bit from our camera:

```
function Camera:send(shader, view_name, proj_name)
    shader:send(view_name or "u_view", self.view:to_vec4s())
    shader:send(proj_name or "u_projection", self.projection:to_vec4s())
end
```

Comment: How do you apply these matrices? And how is your scene defined? The matrices look OK to me. One thing that confuses me is that you start your array indexing by `1`, not by `0`. But I don't know how lua handles this, and especially, how the data is transferred to the GL. However, the result would probably be toally screwed if you were off-by-one here, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, sorry. As for the indexing, Lua indexes from 1, not 0.

Comment: Well. This matrix is just 16 float values. My question targets on finding out how these 16 values are finally used to transform the vertices. Also note that you talk of "meters" and "mm", but the matrix itself is agnostic of any units. It is up to you to design your scene in the "correct" units.

Comment: Right. My units in Blender are set to metric, where 1.0 is a metre. I am setting the camera's near value to 0.001 and far to 10.0. I will update the OP our shader and draw code.

Comment: I don't know how the `shader::send()` abstraction is wroking, but the `to_vec4s`. Matrix uniforms are not splitted to vectors in the GL uniform API. Another thing: `getNormalMatrix` uses `deform_matrix * u_model`, while for transforming the position, you use the opposite multiplication order.

Comment: Oh, thanks for spotting that! As for the `to_vec4s`, it simply converts the flat table into a 4x4 table.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The mat4 library I'm using had a bug where the 16th value was coming out as 1, instead of 0. I found this after comparing my output with GLM's output.